# Método Sort não está ordenando corretamente

Tags: c++, array, classificação

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n, cases = 1, a[3];
cin >> n;
while(cases != n + 1)
{
    cin >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2];

    sort(a, a + 2);

    cout << "Sorted array: " << a[0] << " " << a[1] << " " << a[2] << endl;

    cout << "Case " << cases << ": " << a[1] << endl;

    cases++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Para casos com as entradas: 30 25 15, o array fica: 25 30 15.

Isso seria um bug, ou fui quem implementou de forma errada?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem vários erros. Esse código é basicamente C e não C++. Usar `bits/stdc++.h` não é recomendado, é um desperdício de recurso.

A lógica é bem esquisita. Não está enviando o início e fim do *array* corretamente, não está pegando o último elemento. Só corrigi esse erro que é o que faz a maior diferença.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, cases = 1, a[3];
    cin >> n;
    while (cases != n + 1) {
        cin >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2];
        sort(a, a + 3);
        cout << "Sorted array: " << a[0] << " " << a[1] << " " << a[2] << endl;
        cout << "Case " << cases << ": " << a[1] << endl;
        cases++;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wNkOcu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xdrctegt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/Sort.cpp).

Comment: Entendi, usei a + 2, pois, pensei que funcionasse da seguinte maneira:
a + 0 -> primeira posição
a + 1 -> segundo posição
a + 2 -> terceira posição

Costumo escrever códigos nesse estilo C, pois conheço pouco C++, mas meu objetivo é escrever códigos mais rápidos (para maratonas de programação), tem alguma dica para eu melhorar meus códigos?
Obrigado!

Comment: Aí você tem que fazer perguntas específicas.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente você não está pedindo para ordenar o último parâmetro.

Seu array tem tamanho 3 e ao chamar o sort, você precisa passar o tamanho 3 para que ele ordene não só as duas primeiras posições, mas também a última.

```
...

sort(a, a + 3);

...
```